# Power for my US laptop in Europe

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, power, charge

I just bought a MacBook Pro in USA. I will get it home in Greece (220V, 50Hz).

What is the usual thing to do, without having to buy a whole new charger? Maybe I can find only the cable somewhere?

---

Edit:

An adapter, like the one suggested should do the trick, but I will have to carry that with me forever. So, I think it makes sense to check if the thing I have circled can be bought (it seems it can be removed (thus if I can buy a European one, Type C, I will be able to insert it there)):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could purchase the ["Apple World Travel Adapter Kit"](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD837AM/A/apple-world-travel-adapter-kit) from an Apple Store or from Apple.com before you leave. I do not know if this kit is available overseas (not the US). $39

EDIT #1:

You could also purchase [this adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016WYL9NY) for only $9. It's much cheaper, and appears to work in Greece. $9

EDIT #2:

If you want *just the piece that goes into the existing charger*, check out [this US to Europe Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004VK475Y). $5

Comment: Oh damn, I had to mention that. I don't want that, 30$ isn't worth it, I want to use it *only* in Greece.

Comment: How about [this adapter](https://www.amazon.com/Yubi-Power-Universal-Adapter-Outlets/dp/B016WYL9NY/)? It says it works in Greece. $9.

Comment: I think I found the exact one in RadioShack in Fan Francisco, near Mission St. However, it said 250V and 10/16 A. I think they look alike, I will go and check! Thanks man, probably you can update your answer with that...However, I would be also interested one buying a cable for the charger. However, I don't know how to find it (I mean how it is called)!  Picasso woke up within me, check my update!

Comment: [Check this out.](https://www.amazon.com/Europe-Converter-Charger-Adapter-MacBook/dp/B004VK475Y/). Looks like what you're after, for $5.

Comment: Hurray! You are a genius..However, I would rather walk up in a store and buy it, so if you have some idea let me know...I am in San Francisco! If not, I will look...! :)

Comment: Have you tried [Fry's Electronics in Palo Alto](http://www.frys.com/ac/storeinfo/palo_alto-location-frys-electronics-hours-maps-directions)? Online, they have *some* European converters, but not that last one I found. If I were in need of an in-person buying solution, I'd try Radio Shack or Fry's.

Comment: I don't have a car, and getting into the public transport is just too much overhead for me. Thanks a ton for your valuable help!

Comment: Frysk, sorry for commenting again, but it seems there is no Fry's in SF that I can approach by foot. I will go to RadioShack, but I doubt they will have it. Do you know if the link in Amazon you posted will ship it from Europe to San Francisco? I am asking because I am worried about the shipping costs...I mean I will be in Greece in 1 month. However, I wouldn't mind paying a dollar or two, if I could take care of  that now, so I don't have it in my mind!

Comment: @gsamaras It's shipping from California, most likely. You could have it in as soon as a couple of days. At most, maybe 5-7 days. I've never had anything take longer than a week from Amazon.com.